# Get the mean of sequence of frames

Tags: opencv, element, frames, mean, mat

I want to calculate the mean of the sequence of frames by adding them and then divide by the total number of frames. The problem is that i can't access the pixels in the image. I used this code.

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++){
 image = imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
 Mat Mean = Mat::zeros(width, height,image.type());
        for(w = 0; w < image.rows ; w++)
           for(h = 0; h < image.cols ; h++)
               Mean.row(w).col(h) += (image.at<unsigned float>(w,h) / N);
         }
```

I'm always having an Assertion Failed error.
I also tried:

```
(float)image.at<uchar>(w,h)

image.row(w).col(h)[0]

image.row(w).col(h).val[0]
```

but in vain.

Here is the working code...but i can't display the final result because it's float.

```
Mat Mean   = Mat::zeros(width, height,CV_32F); 
for(i = 1; i <= framesToLearn ; i++){
        image = imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
        accumulate(image, Mean);
    }
    Mean = Mean /framesToLearn;
    imshow("mean",Mean);
    waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try using a different approach: `cv::accumulate`:

```
cv::Mat avgImg;
avgImg.create(width, height,CV_32FC3);

for(i = 1; i <= N; i++){
  image = imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
  cv::accumulate(image, avgImg);
}

avgImg = avgImg / N;
```

Notice that if you need to show the result image you will have to convert it to `CV_8U` or to normalize it, for example:

```
Mat Mean   = Mat::zeros(width, height,CV_32F); 
 for(i = 1; i <= framesToLearn ; i++){
      image = imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
      accumulate(image, Mean);
    }
 Mean = Mean /framesToLearn;
 Mean.convertTo(Mean,CV_8U);
 imshow("mean",Mean);
 waitKey(0);
```

---

Comment: The results are right but i can't show them usong imshow()....it's just a white image.

Comment: You should convert to `uint8` instead of `float32 `

Comment: I changed CV_32FC3 to CV_32S and get runtime error because the different data types.

Comment: read the documentation - it says that it supports only float 32 and float 64

Answer (score 0):

just don't overcomplicate it, avoid the inner loops:

```
Mat Mean = Mat::zeros(width, height,CV_32F);
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    Mean += imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
}
Mean /= N;
```

and yes, if you wnat to access single pixels, you *have* to use:

image.at(r,c);

Comment: I tried your code and i have a run time error as shown here... https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx0nckxmik5fgvm/Untitled.jpg

Comment: probably, because N===small here